# Continue isnt working properly

Tags: python, while-loop, continue

I do need help in solving my code.
Below python code 'continue' is not working properly

```
dicemp = {'12345':''}
while(1):
    choice =  int(input("Please enter your choice\n"))

    if (choice == 1):
        empno = input("Enter employee number: ")
        for i in dicemp.keys():
            if i == empno:
                print("employee already exists in the database")
                continue
        print("Hello")
```

Output:

Please enter your choice

1

Enter employee number: 12345

employee already exists in the database

Hello

So for the above code if I give same employee no. 12345 it is going into if block and printing the message"employee already exists in the database" after this it should continue from start but in this case it is also printing "hello".

Comment: The "hello" will be printed when the loop is finished. The loop finishes regardless wheter the employee already exists in the database.

Comment: there are 2 loops. After the `for` loop has terminated, it prints Hello. `continue` works for your `for` loop, not `while`

Comment: Then the print Statement should be in the loop

Comment: So how should I make it work for while loop, any suggestions. I want the loop to start over if employee no. already exists

Comment: BTW: `for i in dicemp.keys(): if i == empno:` can be replaced with just `if empno in dicemp:`

Comment: Thanks madPhysicist, i replaced my code with your suggestion and it worked..Thanks alot!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `continue` is moving the `for` loop on to its next iteration, which would have happened anyway. If you need to continue the outer loop, you can do something like this:

```
while True:
    choice = int(input("Please enter your choice\n"))

    if choice == 1:
        empno = input("Enter employee number: ")
        found = False
        for i in dicemp:
            if i == empno:
                print("employee already exists in the database")
                found = True
                break
         if found:
             continue
         print("Hello")
```

Now the `continue` is outside the `for` loop, so it will continue the outer loop.

You could simplify this to:

```
while True:
    choice = int(input("Please enter your choice\n"))
    if choice==1:
        empno = input("Enter employee number: ")
        if empno in dicemp:
            print("employee already exists in the database")
            continue
        print("Hello")
```

and get rid of the inner loop entirely.

Comment: Yeah!! My bad..I am new to programming so lot of mistakes :P